# Button not changing in table accordion

Tags: html, css

Why +/- button doesn't work when clicking the button the accordion is working fine just the button no changing is there any error? could be the **.accordion-button: after** try use before but also not working. Below are example of my problem. example codepen >>> [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kaiyen725/pen/JjaqoQB)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="accordion-row">
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Info 1 <button class="accordion-button"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="accordion-content">
      <td colspan="3">More info about Item 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.accordion-button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr .accordion-button:after {
  content: "+";
}

 .accordion-row.active .accordion-button:after {
  content: "-";
}
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-content.active {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```
 const accordionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button');

accordionButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const contentRow = button.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    contentRow.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: The selector `.accordion-row.active .accordion-button:after` does not apply - because you did not add the `active` class to the row that contains the button, but to the _next_ row, `.accordion-content`

Comment: @CBroe just now forgot to add the js code so basically when click the button will add active class to the button

Comment: _"so basically when click the button will add active class to the button"_ - that is not what your shown code does.

Comment: @CBroe ok I get what you mean thanks. So I add one more toggle to the button class, and change the css to  .accordion-button:after {
  content: "+";
}

 .accordion-button.active:after {
  content: "-";
}

Comment: Codepen link gives a 404

Comment: updated correct codepen